# Little Snitch Map show Unknown Location and Private Network

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, little-snitch

Late 2012 iMac running macOS High Sierra and Little Snitch version 4.1.3

When I open the map it shows to Icons, one Unknown Location and the other Private Network.

I denied access to Unknown location since it is running under AirPort Utility and it shows iPv4 address 225.255.255.255 and I do not use the AirPort Utility application.

Private Network is more confusing since I am not sure what applications are responsible for this Network.

Any suggestions on how to identify the players responsible for the Private Network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

225.255.255.255 is your local network's [Broadcast address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address). It specifically refers to the [default domain 0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) & is never passed across a boundary - so never leaves your house.

In very broad terms, it is used so devices can find each other - don't block it.

Any address considered as a [Private Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) will also not cross boundaries.
You didn't tell us precisely the address you are referring to, but in all likelihood it will be in the range 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x or perhaps 172.16.x.x or even 169.254.x.x [which is a self-assigned, or [Link Local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) address]

You should generally not block any of these either.